Condition for quadratic form to have a chi-squared distribution
According to Seber and Lee's textbook theorem 2.8: If $\mathbf{Y} \sim N_n(\mathbf{0},\Sigma)$ and $A$ is symmetric then $\mathbf{Y}^TA\mathbf{Y} \sim \chi^2_r$ if and only if $r$ of the eigenvalues of $A\Sigma$ are $1$ and the rest are zero.
The book gives the proof for the $\Rightarrow$ direction but states that the proof for the $\Leftarrow$ direction is just the reverse of the proof of the $\Rightarrow$ direction.
I tried to reverse the proof, however, the proof for the $\Rightarrow$ direction uses the fact that $R^TAR$ is symmetric and idempotent where $\Sigma = RR^T$ to establish that $\operatorname{rank}(R^TAR) = \operatorname{trace}(R^TAR)$. This is the step of the proof I don't know how to reverse because we don't know if $R^TAR$ is symmetric and idempotent. Could anyone give me some clarification? Note that we are not assuming that $A$ or $\Sigma$ are invertible.

Let $\Sigma^{1/2}$ be symmetric semi-positive definite with $\Sigma^{1/2}\Sigma^{1/2}=\Sigma$ and note that the eigenvalues of $A\Sigma$ are those of $\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2}.$

Just for further information, Seber and Lee gave a special result. There is a counterpart for non-central chi-square too.
